# How do I get version of MPC, not MPD

Tags: mpd, mpc

Using Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, but using putty from Windows, so... CLI.

When I type:

`mpc version`

it reports the version of the mpd daemon.

How can I get the version of the mpc controller, not the daemon?

Thanks.

Mark.

PS, how can I get the latest version of mpc?
Ubuntu repositories are horribly out of date. I'd rather not update mpd as it seems to be working fine.

M.

Answer (score 0):

The `mpc` command itself has no awareness of its own version. What you can do instead, though, is ask Ubuntu what version you have installed:

```
phrogz@music:~$ apt-cache policy mpc
mpc:
  Installed: 0.27-1
  Candidate: 0.27-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.27-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Also, note that the version reported by `mpc version` is (confusingly) not the MPD version either, but [returns the *protocol* version](http://mailman.blarg.de/pipermail/mpd-devel/2016-July/000564.html).

```
gkistner@music:~$ mpc version
mpd version: 0.19.0

gkistner@music:~$ mpd --version | head -1
Music Player Daemon 0.19.10
```